# Unable to Access WD External Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I have a 2 TB Western Digital External Hard Drive (Model - My Book). A couple of months back, it suddenly stopped working. I was very busy then and so couldn't focus on fixing it. Now I want to resolve this issue and hence seeking your help.

Current state of the drive -

- The LED switches on
- I could feel the drive spinning when I touch the hard disk
- No weird sounds or cracks from the drive
- The drive appaers in the USB removal area ([http://imgur.com/JxpyRTY](https://imgur.com/JxpyRTY)) but not in File/Windows Explorer ([http://imgur.com/A59FKhE](https://imgur.com/A59FKhE))
- The drive shows as "Unallocated" in the Disk Manager. ([http://imgur.com/ocWjPOL](https://imgur.com/ocWjPOL))
- If I memory serves me right, earlier when the drive initially stopped working, it was showing as "RAW" in the Disk Manager. In my eagerness to fix the issue, I downloaded "MiniTool Partition Wizard" and clciked "Rebuild MBR". I don't know what it is but I selected it. That's the only action I took until today after the drive stopped working
- I downloaded the WD Drive Utilities application and ran the available tests.
- The drive passed the SMART test without any issues.([http://imgur.com/uNJPbvm](https://imgur.com/uNJPbvm))
- To troubleshoot, I changed the power cable, USB Cable and tested it. No success so far

The drive had around 1800 GB of data before it stopped working. I would be very thankful if you can help me acccess the drive

Comment: have tried simple tool like TestDisk 6 see http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: By access do you mean to recover the data or just use it as a new disk?

Comment: @TomYan By access I mean access to the data. Once I can get to the data, I will backup and format the drive

Comment: @dExIT I tried TestDisk and one partition was found. However after "Writing" the partition, now the disk display as "RAW" in Disk Manager